# separate texts from a href in same td with XPath python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-crawler

I have an HTML webpage like this:

```
<tr><td style="text-align:center;">7</td><td class="multi_row" style="line-height:15px;">Loaded on 'NYK LEO 303W' at Port of Loading<br> <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" style="line-height:15px;" title="NYK LEO" data-click="vesselPop" data-cd="NLZT0303W">NYK LEO 303W</a></td><td class="multi_row" style="line-height:15px;">VANCOUVER, BC ,CANADA<br>  <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" style="line-height:15px;" onclick="openLocationPopup('CAVAN01')" title="3891 DELTAPORT GCT">3891 DELTAPORT GCT</a></td><td class="ico_e">2018-10-26 23:30</td></tr>
```

I want to separate the  `<a href>`'s string part in one variable and have a pure text like 'bla bla bla' in another variable.
this is what i have done till now:

```
event_path = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='detail']//tr/td[2]")
event = [cell.text for cell in event_path]
```

its for the text part
and this one is for the string in  :

```
vessel_path = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='detail']//tr/td[2]/a")
vessel = [cell.text.split(' ')[:2] for cell in vessel_path]
```

the `split(' ')[:2]` is cuz the data is sth like this : NYK LEO 303W and i just need words not the number (it can be done more reliable with regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below to get only first text node from `td`

```
event = [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', cell).strip() for cell in event_path]
```

Comment: can you edit it? its not under function and cell) ? it make errors.

Comment: it returns this error : selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/safaridriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Comment: no it was a bug i restart machine it fixed. it seprate the text but how can i get the text inside <a href>

Comment: @iman_sh77 , do you mean `vessel = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in vessel_path]`?

Comment: do you know any pythonic way to implement whole demand ? cuz i dont want to break the unity of the code

Comment: @iman_sh77, how do you want data to look like? Share in which format you want to get required values

Comment: for e.g i have :'Loaded on 'NYK LEO 303W' at Port of Loading
NYK LEO 303W' in a whole td which are separated with a <br> and <a href> so i want first part in event var and NYK which is a link in another var

Comment: @iman_sh77 , still not sure I understand. Can you update question with your real HTML?

Comment: @iman_sh77 , ok, so you want to get `"Loaded on 'NYK LEO 303W' at Port of Loading"` and `"NYK LEO 303W"` separately? Or as second string you want no the *link text*, but *value of `@href`*?

Comment: the first option you said is correct i dont need the link

Comment: @iman_sh77 , so you want to get those two values for each `td`? Do you want both in single line?  How should it looks like? Like list of two strings or key-value pair in dictionary? Share example of output

Comment: event = 'Loaded on 'NYK LEO 303W' at Port of Loading
NYK LEO 303W' and vessel = 'NYK LEO' without the number part

Comment: @iman_sh77 , so the problem is in this line `vessel = [cell.text.split(' ')[:2] for cell in vessel_path]` right? You want this line re-factoring?

Comment: Try `vessel = [cell.text.rsplit(" ", 1)[0] for cell in vessel_path]` to ignore last substring

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code :

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_classname("multi_row")

for element in elements
    print(element.text)
```

Comment: that's not possible to get it by class_name cuz there is another table which has multi_row class name and something else: the output is not separate with the <a href> one

Comment: change driver.find_elements_by_classname("multi_row") to driver.find_elements_by_classname("//table[@id='detail']//tr/td[2]")

Comment: doesnt matter it contains NYK LEO 303W part which i dont want

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I see vessel that you are expecting is already present in title attribute of anchor.

If it is a valid case, then you can get it directly from attibutes like,

```
vessel_path = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='detail']//tr/td[2]/a")
vessel = [cell.get_attribute("title") for cell in vessel_path]
```